# Create table in PostgresQL 9.1 from JSON

Tags: json, postgresql

I am wanting to create a table in `PostgresQL 9.1` from a `JSON`.

I have created a table from a `CSV` now trying to do it from a `JSON`.

Am I able to do this?

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    'id': 234345346, 
    'account_id': 34664, 
    'address': '11 Long St, Frankston VIC 3443, Australia', 
    'category_id': 125051, 
    'description': None, 
    'is_anonymous': False, 
    'iso_created_at': '2017-05-24T10:15:48+10:00', 
    'location': {
        'latitude': -31.6445645669669, 
        'longitude': 152.80345668635
     },
     'report_state_id': 124566958, 
     'title': 'Small stack 2012', 
     'user_id': 564777, 
     'shape_id': None
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you mean "populate" (fill), not create? Either way, there are no json features in 9.1, you'll need to use an external tool.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL only started supporting JSON in 9.2, so you'll need to update.

[Source](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/)

If you're unable to upgrade, there is a backport called `json91` which can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/adunstan/json_91

But you really should upgrade instead of relying on this.

---

Also this is not valid JSON.

JSON has no type `None`. A common use for a key with no value is `null`

> In JSON, values must be one of the following data types:
>
> - a string
> - a number
> - an object (JSON object)
> - an array
> - a boolean
> - null
>
> [Source](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_datatypes.asp)

Secondly, and I believe this depends on what actually receives your data, JSON doesn't allow for single quoted strings.

You can read the spec for JSON here: http://www.json.org/